# Method adds not a necessary line to a list when it should not do so

Tags: c#, regex, text

I'm a beginner in c# and I am working with text exercises. I made a method to filter vehicle's plate numbers. It should consist of 3 letters and 3 integers ( AAA:152 ). My method sends the wrong plate numbers to a file, but also it adds that bad number to a good ones list.

```
private static string[] InvalidPlates(string[] csvLines, int fieldToCorrect)
{
    var toReturn = new List<string>();
    var toSend = new List<string>();

    int wrongCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < csvLines.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] stringFields = csvLines[i].Split(csvSeparator[0]);
        string[] values = stringFields[fieldToCorrect].Split(':');

        if(Regex.IsMatch(values[0], @"^[a-zA-Z]+$") && Regex.IsMatch(values[1], "^[0-9]+$"))
        {
            toReturn.Add(string.Join(csvSeparator, stringFields));
        }
        else
        {
            toSend.Add(string.Join(csvSeparator, stringFields));
            wrongCount++;
        }
    }

    WriteLinesToFile(OutputFile, toSend.ToArray(), wrongCount);
    return toReturn.ToArray();
}
```

Can somebody help me to fix that?

Comment: may be: @"^[a-zA-Z]{3}$" and "^[0-9]{3}$", because otherwise, a plate ABCDEFG:123456 will be valid.

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a [mcve]? It seems to me that we don't need most of this code - just code the demonstrates a *single* concrete example, with expected results and actual results. Currently it's unclear whether the colon in your example is separating examples or part of the example, or exactly what's happening. (I *think* it's part of the example, but you complain that it's adding a "bad number" to the "good list", and the example you've given looks like it should be in the good list anyway...)

Comment: Just `if(Regex.IsMatch(stringFields[fieldToCorrect], @"^[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{3}$"))` should suffice.

Comment: `toReturn` and `toSend` are adding the exact same thing. The only difference is the `wrongCount` increment.

Comment: @DGibbs: Yes, and that's fine, isn't it? The point is it's adding each entry to one of those lists.

Comment: It's not clear why you're splitting things anyway. Why not just a single regex of `"^[a-zA-Z]{3}:[0-9]{3}$"`?

Comment: @DGibbs toSend is written to a file, toReturn is returned. I think he expects toReturn to contain only valid plates while toSend to only invalid ones.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yep, missed the `return toReturn.ToArray();` line.

Comment: @JonSkeet As i have mentioned. I'm a beginner. Thanks for that!

Comment: @OguzOzgul exactly. Any suggestions on how to do so?

Comment: Everyone pointed out that your regular expression patterns are invalid for testing a valid plate. Your test succeeds for plates like ABABABABABABABABABA:132123123123123123, you should specify the length constraint. And as also pointed out, do not split the strings, just use a single regular expression, check Jon Skeet's comment with that single regex

Comment: You need to show the following: your CSV (minimal, reproducable example, one line is enough); your expected `toReturn` and `toSend`; your actual `toReturn` and `toSend` after you have executed your program. Then, it will be absolutely easy to find a problem.

Comment: @OguzOzgul I made a single expression now, but that does not fix a problem for me. I can't understand why does it add the wrong ones to a list.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev 

Line in csv : S*L:125. I do not want to add this to toReturn list, instead i want this to be added to toSend list. It actually adds it to a toSend list but to toReturn aswell.

Comment: It is impossible for a plate to be added to both lists, according to the code you provided.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev any thoughts?

Comment: @OguzOzgul somehow it adds it. don't know what to do actually..

Comment: Can you show your exact input - using your code if I input just a single element array containing _"S*L:125"_, then toSend contains that & toReturn is empty. If I use a two element array with the second element as  _"SAL:125"_ which is valid - then toSend & toReturn just contain 1 element each - which is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to constrain the possible length using quantifiers:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}\:\d{3}$
```

which literally means the following, in the strict order:

> the strings begins from exactly 3 lowercase or uppercase English alphabet letters, continues with semicolon (`:`), and ends with exactly three digits

Remember that `\` should be escaped in C#.

Also, there is no need to join `stringFields` back into a string, when you can use non-splitted `csvLines[i]`:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(stringFields, @"^[a-zA-Z]{3}\\:\\d{3}$"))
    toReturn.Add(csvLines[i]);
}
else
{
    toSend.Add(csvLines[i]);
    wrongCount++;
}
```

Another important thing is that your code is incorrect in terms of OOP. It is pretty inobvious that your method called `InvalidPlates` will save something to a file. It may confuse you after some time or other developers. There should be no "hidden" functionality, and all methods should actually do only the one thing.

Here is how I would do this using LINQ:

```
private static bool IsACorrectPlate(string p) => Regex.IsMatch(p, @"^[a-zA-Z]{3}\:\d{3}$");

private static void SortPlatesOut(string[] csvLines, int column, out string[] correct, out string[] incorrect)
{
    var isCorrect = csvLines
        .GroupBy(l => IsACorrectPlate(l.Split(';')[column]))
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray());

    correct = isCorrect[true];
    incorrect = isCorrect[false];
}

// Usage:
string[] incorrect, correct;

SortPlatesOut(csvLines, 1, out correct, out incorrect);

File.WriteAllLines("", incorrect);
// do whatever you need with correct
```

Now, `SortPlatesOut` method has an expectable behavior without side effects. The code has also become two times shorter. At the same time, it looks more readable for me. If it looks non-readable for you, you can unpack LINQ and split some things other things up.